# Error validating form with a regular expression

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, codeigniter-3

I'm using this regular expression validation with codeigniter 3.x

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('FieldName','FriendlyName','trim|required|regex_match[/^([a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1})$|^([0-9]{11})$/]');
```

This regex is made to grab a Fiscal Code or an Italian VAT Code (alternatively)

I receive this error

> Severity: Warning Message: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

What's the matter? I see the '/' char at the beginning and at the end of my regex call...

Thanks

Comment: Make a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the regex part in different way because **pipe( | )** is creating problem.

When Codeigniter tries to convert this line to form rules array

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules(
'FieldName',
'FriendlyName',
'trim|required|regex_match[/^([a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1})$|^([0-9]{11})$/]');
```

Codeigniter will get this :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => trim
    [1] => required
    [2] => regex_match[/^([a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1})$
    [3] => ^([0-9]{11})$/]
)
```

but correct conversion should be like this :-

```
Array
(
    [0] => trim
    [1] => required
    [2] => regex_match[/^([a-zA-Z]{6}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{2}[a-zA-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}[a-zA-Z]{1})$^([0-9]{11})$/]
)
```

So apply this regex in such a way that **|** should not be used in regex part.